# Should tag descriptions be prefixed with their kanji/kana equivalent?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I've noticed that a few tag descriptions are prefixed with a kanji (or kana) version of their text:

- [kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kanji) - 漢字: Chinese characters as used in Japanese writing as opposed to the two kana syllabaries and romaji Latin letters.
- [kana](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kana) - かな: Covers both Japanese syllabaries, hiragana (ひらがな) and katakana (かたかな).
- [spoken-language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoken-language) - 口語. Words that exist in speech but not in writing. Also refers to things like contractions, omissions, or other verbal mechanisms characteristic of speech.
- [anime](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime) - アニメ: How the language is used in Japanese animation.
- [bikago](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bikago) - 美化語 - making words polite (美化 - literally: beautification) by adding the prefix お/ご(御)to a word.

I've followed this pattern when adding descriptions for the [manga](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga) and [music](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) tags.

Others follow a slightly different pattern, using parentheses instead:

- [rendaku](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rendaku) - Rendaku (連濁) is a phonological phenomenon in Japanese by which the first consonant of the second component of a compound word often becomes voiced (k→g, s→z, t→d and h→b).
- [ichidan-verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ichidan-verbs) - Ichidan verbs (一段活用) are verbs like たべる and おきる, which conjugate after dropping the terminal る, e.g. たべない, たべます, たべる, たべれば, たべよう.
- [godan-verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/godan-verbs) - Godan verbs (五段活用) are verbs like のむ and あるく, which conjugate by changing their last kana, e.g. のまない, のみます, のむ, のめば, のもう.
- [hentaigana](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hentaigana) - Hentaigana (変体仮名) are variant forms of hiragana that were used prior to 1900, but which are no longer in use.
- [manyogana](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manyogana) - Manyogana (万葉仮名) is an old system of writing that uses kanji purely for their phonetic values, and takes its name from its use in the Manyoshu (c. 750 CE).

I'm just wondering if there's any "preferred style" for this sort of thing, for the sake of consistency?

(Obviously, it's not necessary for *every* tag to follow this format; for example, [grammar](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) or [translation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) are fine as they are.)

Comment: Kanji and Kana both might also be good, following & separated from the English Tag Name by a space + right forward diagonal + a space, and also separated thusly from each other, (rather than using parentheses)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's nice to have the equivalent Japanese right at the start, also when thinking about accessibility for native speakers. Repeating the tag word in its romanization doesn't really serve any purpose.

In fact, I think it wouldn't hurt to add a Japanese translation for all tags, including tags like [grammar](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar).

> [grammar](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar)
>   文法. A collective term for syntax (the way...

As for style, I like the period (not the colon) as above. (I think the (Western) period is the most discreet punctuation we can put there.)

---

**Update**. This has been implemented. Also see [Please help translate our tags](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/please-help-translate-our-tags).