# An unofficial style guide to our tag wikis

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, formatting

I've been [updating tag excerpts with Japanese translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/please-help-translate-our-tags). The format of our tag wikis is inconsitent, so I'd like to record what format I've followed for the tag wikis I've edited, in case anyone would like to update tag wikis and follow the same format.

---

#### tag excerpt

> [grammar](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar)
>   文法. A collective term for ...

That is

```
[Japanese translation][Western period] [Description of tag in English]
```

The description doesn't repeat the tag name, nor the Japanese translation. If you use `is` or `used to` in the first few words of the description, the tag excerpt will only display what follows this `is`/`used to`, i.e. try to avoid "文法. Grammar is a collective ...", because it will render as "a collective ..." and the Japanese translation won't be seen.

---

#### tag wiki

```
[Detailed tag wiki]

___

*Related tags*

- [tag:first-related-tag]
- [tag:second-related-tag]

___

*See also*

- [Wikipedia link in English](https://link.to.wikipedia/)
- [Wikipedia link in Japanese](https://link.to.wikipedia/)
- [whatever other relevant link](https://other.link/)
```

which renders as

> [Detailed tag wiki]
>
> ---
>
> *Related tags*
>
> - [first-related-tag](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-related-tag)
> - [second-related-tag](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/second-related-tag)
>
> ---
>
> *See also*
>
> - [Wikipedia link in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/)
> - [Wikipedia link in Japanese](https://ja.wikipedia.org/)
> - [whatever other relevant link](http://other.link/)

I think using `*` for italics, `-` for itemized lists and `_` for the horizontal rules keeps the code most readable. I'd also use `**` for bold.

Under *Related tags* I usually just list the tags. Hovering over them gives the tag excerpt which usually explains how the related tag is different quite well.

---

#### text

- use double quotation marks instead of single ones
- avoid quotation marks with Japanese, e.g.

  > <s>The particle "か"</s> (here especially hard to read, `か"` looks like `が`)
  >   The particle か (easy to read)

---

Please feel free to add to these rules (or suggest improvements).

Answer (score -2):

I have a suggestion, having arrived here organically by searching for "Japanese tags?" on Meta:

The tags should probably have Japanese as the term most quickly parsed for search. It's very convoluted to be typing a question about 文法 or 謙譲語 and have to stop and translate your concept into English, especially if you are not a proficient English speaker.

Right now if you type the Japanese word that describes a popular such tag, nothing happens.

Does that work with your suggestion, or is it more drastic?

Comment: There are some tags that are registered as "tag synonyms", which means that they appear when you type, for example `ことわざ`. Are you suggesting we do this for all tags? If so, maybe you can post this as a new discussion/"question".